# How to fix Dropdown on mouse over not working

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I am developing a website. I have created the header; inside the header, I have the logo and a `nabar` which sticks to the top on scroll.

but when the header sticks to the top, my `dropdown` contents inside the `navbar` won't show when I move my mouse over the trigger link.

I have tried this CSS code `.navbar .dropdown:hover dropbtn {display: block; }`

```html
<div class="navbar" id="sticky_header">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown 
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

```css
.navbar {
    width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: darkred;
  font-family: monospace;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 17px 0px black;
}

/* Links inside the navbar */
.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
    border-right: 2px solid white;
}

/* The dropdown container */
.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

/* Dropdown button */
.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px; 
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit; /* Important for vertical align on mobile phones */
  margin: 0; /* Important for vertical align on mobile phones */
}

/* Add a red background color to navbar links on hover */
.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #002500;
}

/* Dropdown content (hidden by default) */
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
    border-bottom: 2px dotted #ccc;
}

/* Add a grey background color to dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #002500;
    border-bottom: 2px dotted #002500;
    color: white;
}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```
<script>
//STICKY HEADER
// When the user scrolls the page, execute myFunction 
window.onscroll = function() {fixHeader();};


// Get the header
var header = document.getElementById("sticky_header");

// Get the offset position of the navbar
var sticky = header.offsetTop;

// Add the sticky class to the header when you reach its scroll position. Remove "sticky" when you leave the scroll position
function fixHeader() {
  if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
    header.classList.add("sticky");
  } else {
    header.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: your actual problem not showing in your provided code

Comment: I don't know where the problem is. That's why I asked here. You can answer if you know the solution, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `.dropdown-content` to `position: fixed` when the navbar is sticky

see below

```js
//STICKY HEADER
// When the user scrolls the page, execute myFunction 
window.onscroll = function() {fixHeader();};


// Get the header
var header = document.getElementById("sticky_header");

// Get the offset position of the navbar
var sticky = header.offsetTop;

// Add the sticky class to the header when you reach its scroll position. Remove "sticky" when you leave the scroll position
function fixHeader() {
  if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
    header.classList.add("sticky");
  } else {
    header.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

```css
.navbar {
    width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: darkred;
  font-family: monospace;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 17px 0px black;
}

/* Links inside the navbar */
.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
    border-right: 2px solid white;
}

/* The dropdown container */
.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

/* Dropdown button */
.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px; 
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit; /* Important for vertical align on mobile phones */
  margin: 0; /* Important for vertical align on mobile phones */
}

/* Add a red background color to navbar links on hover */
.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #002500;
}

/* Dropdown content (hidden by default) */
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
    border-bottom: 2px dotted #ccc;
}

/* Add a grey background color to dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #002500;
    border-bottom: 2px dotted #002500;
    color: white;
}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
.sticky {
position:fixed;
}
/* show the dropdown when sticky*/
.sticky .dropdown-content {
position:fixed;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar" id="sticky_header">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown 
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
<div style="height:200vh">Dummy content</div>
```

Comment: @Jay If it works be sure to mark the answer as correct!